Call API Connector with Google Apps Script
We are using Google sheets and API Connector add-on to fetch data from various APIs. Requests are set and are working and only thing I need to do is to select Add-Ons -> API Connector -> Refresh All Now. After that I want to perform some actions via script.
When I create for example macro to call this func, it tries to call refreshRequests() function, but if you run it, it will exit with ReferenceError: refreshRequests is not defined.
What I am trying to do for example:
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('N1').activate();
  
  refreshRequests();
}

What I want: refresh data by calling API Connector's function
Is there a way to call API Connector's refreshRequests() function from apps script code?
